# System.Printing.PrintServer Win32Exception Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: c#, .net

I occasionally get an unanticipated exception thrown when I try creating a new variable in my code, and I am at a total loss trying to understand what might be causing the issue.

Any guidance or suggestions will be gratefully received

Thanks!

---

The code ...

```
using System.Printing;

var ps = new PrintServer();
```

The exception ...

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot create a file when that file already exists
    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.get_CurrentDispatcher()
    at System.Printing.PrintServer.Initialize(String path, String[] propertiesFilter, PrinterDefaults printerDefaults)
    at System.Printing.PrintServer..ctor()
```

namespace System.Printing info ...

```
#region Assembly System.Printing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Printing.dll
#endregion
```

Comment: What you put as `the code` is not the code... give us the actual line where it fails. And some surrounding code while you're at it

Comment: Check the event log.

Comment: The machine you're running on may be out of (GDI) resources. `RegisterClassEx` is failing, but the code that's calling it takes care to make the class name unique with a GUID, so the issue is not that there's a duplicate. Nor would you normally ever expect `RegisterClassEx` to fail, except under circumstances like desktop heap exhaustion, so check for that. More esoteric problems are also possible (like injection from a rogue DLL that's inappropriately hooking functions). The application itself is probably blameless. If all this sounds like Chinese to you, reinstalling may be faster. :-P

Comment: @MichaelP, I'm having this exact same issue.  Were you ever able to find a cause?